# On OS X, using Terminal, is there a way to get rid of the scroll bar?

Tags: macos, terminal.app, iterm, scrollbar

I've been going back and forth a bit between iTerm and Terminal lately.  They both have their pros and cons, but at this point I've more or less settled on Terminal.  (The reason, if you're curious, is that I can use <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to switch between tabs, just like in all my other programs.)

However, I like to remove as much visual clutter as possible in my work environments, and the one thing I really miss about iTerm is the ability to get rid of the scroll bar.  Is it possible to do this in Terminal?  I've done some googling and turned up a number of answers, but none of them seem to actually work any more.

Specifically, there don't seem to be any settings in the options dialogs for it, adding "Scrollbar: FALSE" or "Scrollbar: NO" to the com.apple.Terminal.plist file doesn't seem to work, and even setting the Scrollback to 0 doesn't seem to get rid of the scroll bar (though it does get rid of the scrollback buffer, which I do *not* want to do).

If anybody knows how to do this, I'd be terribly grateful.  Alternatively, if you know how to get iTerm to switch tabs with <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>, that would also be great.

Comment: Forget about wasted space. This wastes time.

Comment: I would much rather waste time in the pursuit of beauty than waste screen real estate.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (The reason, if you're curious, is that I can use `<cmd-]>` and `<cmd-[>` to switch between tabs, just like in all my other programs.)

Huh?

For me in Terminal, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> switch windows, not tabs, and this is non-standard behaviour not replicated in any of my other programs as far as I know. In Safari <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> are the back/forward history shortcuts.

The more MacOSX standard way of switching application windows is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>. The standard for switching tabs is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>. All the standard shortcuts work in iTerm, Terminal, and Safari.

That said, you're in luck. You can set [Application-specific shortcuts in Snow Leopard](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8564.html) for iTerm in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts. The relevant menu commands to change are `Select Previous Tab` and `Select Next Tab` of course.

Since Apple added the ability to split the pane horizontally, they removed the ability to hide the scollbar. I know of no way of hiding it in the post-Tiger Terminal application.

Comment: Doh!  I did indeed leave out the shift - I meant to write <shift-cmd-[> and <shift-cmd-]> to switch tabs.  Those do work in Terminal and Safari, but I can't get it to work in iTerm by default.  Updating the Keyboard Shortcuts worked like a charm, though.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah! Shift! Right! Guess there's more than one shortcut for the tab switching thing. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: This really does not answer the question ... and people looking to remove that stupid ugly scrollbar in terminal.app come here, and see this "just use iterm.app, its better" post that is not what people are looking for.

Comment: @Evgeny I disagree. The answer "Since Apple added the ability to split the pane horizontally, they removed the ability to hide the scollbar" does, in fact, answer the question. It simply can't be done. What would be a better answer?